# Table transformation Google Sheets

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, transpose, flatten, google-query-language

I'm trying to convert such table:

[image: pic1]

into such table:

[image: pic2]

First table is very big, and is being changed automatically by another user.

I'd like to use Google Sheets' `query` function. Any idea how?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(B1:D1&"×"&A2:A&"×"&B2:D), "×"), 
 "where Col2 is not null"))
```

[image]